# Building a simple .htaccess hierachy rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I'm trying to do something rather simple here, but haven't been able to find the solution for it by searching here or Google - it must be that I don't know exactly what to search for.

Basically, I'm trying to do this with my .htaccess file:

www.mydomain.com/$ **shows** www.mydomain.com/$.php

and

www.mydomain.com/products/$ **shows** www.mydomain.com/products/$.php

Also, what is your favourite resource for learning how to code .htaccess files? I know my question is a simple one, and I would much like to be able to do things like this on my own from now on.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to add a '.php' to every request. You could use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

to achieve this, however it will add a '.php' even if the user requests www.example.com/foo.php so you maybe want to use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.php)?$ $1.php
```

**EDIT:** if you want to allow access to existing files, e.g. css or JavaScript files or images, use RewriteCond:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [END]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me an Internal Server Error now :(

Comment: sorry, you have to use `RewriteRule ^(.*?)(\.php)?$ $1.php [END]`
The `[END]` flag tells the rewrite engine to stop after this rule and not process the request again. The `?` is because the `.*` would "eat" the complete string, including the '.php'.

Comment: I still get the same problem. I thought it might have to do with the other contents of my .htaccess file, so I tried deleted everything and only put the code you gave me. Still a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: you have to write RewriteEngine On in the line before the rule. Also check if the rewrite module is enabled in the httpd.conf and if overriding is enabled.